# HTML5 Projekktor Video Player Works / Plays only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I need your help to sort out a matter which is most probably a banal one for most of you ( I am a beginner...)

So, I am trying to use jquery datepicker together with projekktor to launch a video according to a particular date.
(i have a folder where I store daily timelapse videos....)

Everything works ok so far with below script, i.e. calendar loads properly, and "picked date" starts the correct video.

The point is that it works only once, i.e. when I click on another date, then nothing happens unless I refresh the page and click again on this same other date.

What did I do not understand?

Thank you in advance for your help as I'm struggling now since two long evenings on this.

Kind regards

Daniel from Dubai UAE

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
            inline: true,
            onSelect: function (value, date) {
                var date = value;
                var camera = "Dubai";
                var prefix = date + "_" + camera;
                var video_mp4 = "./medias/Videos/" + prefix + ".mp4";
                var video_ogv = "./medias/Videos/" + prefix + ".ogv";
                var video_webm = "./medias/Videos/" + prefix + ".webm";
                var poster = "./medias/Posters/" + prefix + ".jpg";

                document.getElementById("Daniel").innerHTML = video_mp4;

                projekktor('#player_a', {
                    volume: 0.8,
                    autoplay: true,
                    playlist: [{
                        0: {
                            src: video_mp4,
                            type: 'video/mp4'
                        },
                        1: {
                            src: video_ogv,
                            type: 'video/ogv'
                        },
                        2: {
                            src: video_webm,
                            type: 'video/webm'
                        },
                    }]
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this at the end of your onSelect function:

```
projekktor('player_a').setPlayhead(0);
projekktor('player_a').setPlay();
```